# Sending automatic emails from firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My question is about a possible generic feature of firebase

Is it possible, or firebase allows, to send an email automatically to a specific email address when it´s created, from an app for example, a new entry in the database?

A practical case would be:

A customer buys a product from an app, this order generates a new entry in the real-time database of firebase and at that moment of creating the new entry, I receive an email at my email address notifying me the new order.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do, if you are talking off something like whenever there is a change in database. You should take a look at [database_triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events). There are several examples and sample code available out there. To help you get started, you can look [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/)